# Program that stops me from opening certain programs, on Windows 10

Tags: windows, gratis, productivity

I procrastinate and get distracted easily. I need a free app for Windows 10 that lets me block other apps so I don't do so.

I have tried "Temptation Blocker" but that did not block all apps for me.

Comment: By apps do you mean Windows 10 apps from the Windows app store? Or applications on your desktop computer? (or both?) Can you expand on why "Temptation Blocker" did not block all apps? (What apps didn't it block?)

Comment: Check out 'Parental Control' software

Comment: Maybe you could uninstall the app, or install it as another user? Switching the user would make the startup less immediate.